# How to round or format openquery result? Round() works as expected under SSAS but disappears under openquery

Tags: sql, rounding, openquery

I am trying to round the output I get from SSAS mdx query.

When I run this query on the analysis server it works as expected.

```
WITH MEMBER Result AS Round([Measures].[Avg Movement Length Of Stay Days],2)
SELECT NON EMPTY { Result } ON COLUMNS FROM [Stays]
```

[image]

---

I run the same query as an openquery and my rounding disappears.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ( SSAS ,' WITH MEMBER Result AS Round([Measures].[Avg Movement Length Of Stay Days],2)
SELECT NON EMPTY { Result } ON COLUMNS FROM [Stays] ' )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok. Sorted.

```
SELECT Round("[Measures].[Result]",2) FROM OPENQUERY ( SSAS,' WITH MEMBER Result AS Round([Measures].[Avg Movement Length Of Stay Days],2)
SELECT NON EMPTY { Result } ON COLUMNS FROM [Stays] ' )
```